# Can not press space key CKEDITOR inline

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ckeditor, spaces

I have an issue when using ckeditor 4 ( inline mode). I can click a div and edit it, but I cant press space key. Please tell me how to fix this. [image]

Here is my code

```
<div id="editor1" contenteditable="true">
    <h1>Inline Editing in Action!</h1>
    <p>The "div" element that contains this text is now editable.
</div>
<script>
    // Turn off automatic editor creation first.
    CKEDITOR.disableAutoInline = true;
    CKEDITOR.inline( 'editor1' );
</script>
```

Comment: Since this obviouly not normal behaviour, so you must have done something to cause it, so you'll need to show all **relevant** code, best would be a working example in form of a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/), or other webpage.

Comment: What browser is this? Do you get any console errors?

Comment: Im using FF 32.0.3 and FireBug. No console errors found

Answer (score 0):

I had same issue, after hours of research figured out that **jquery.hotkeys.js** is causing the issue.

Try removing any reference to jquery hot keys and see if it works,